# List of Possible Quantum cryptographic tasks?

Tags: quantum-information, big-list

Other than Shor's algorithm for integer factorization, what are some other algorithms that will benefit from quantum computers?

I am exploring the potential quantum cryptographic tasks.

Comment: This appears to be a list based question, which is generally considered off-topic as *too broad* because essentially all answers are equally valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grover's algorithm: a search algorithm that can be used to break AES encryption.
Arrow, Hassidim & Lloyd's algorithm to solve linear systems of equations.